# how does rotation works in AVL trees and what is a good way to understand it?

Tags: data-structures, search-trees, balanced-search-trees, binary-search-trees

[image]

If we consider this tree with T1 and T2 as subtrees, and we want to rotate on x (rotating the edge between T1 and x), what is the result? how does it work then? Does the x stay in its place and T1 switch with T2? I saw multiple examples online but they had too many nodes and i couldn't really understand the concept of rotating and that's why i chose this simple example so that i (hopefully) can apply it in all other situations.

Comment: Read a textbook. Look at the graphics.

Answer (score 4):

One needs *three* subtrees to describe rotation, as the operation reconnects the three subtrees of a pair of nodes, one the child of the other.

[image]

The operation can be seen as a [associative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property): $T_1\;p\; (T_2\; q\; T_3) = (T_1\; p\; T_2)\; q\; T_3$ of the [inorder traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) of the nodes in a binary tree.

Both the left and right diagram have the inorder $\mathrm{in}(T_1)\; p\; \mathrm{in}(T_2) \; q\; \mathrm{in}(T_3)$, where $\mathrm{in}(T)$ is the inorder of subtree $T$.

It is pretty well explained at wikipedia [Tree rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation), even with animated pictures.

Comment: Oh so the example that I provided isn't rotatable?

Comment: Just look at Wikipedia. It has many illustrations that describe the process.